# Mailer Challenge with Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paypal, actionmailer, mailer

I'm trying to send a mail to the owner of a store after each transaction. Everything else is set up, but i can't seem to get the email address generated.

```
class PaymentNotifier < ActionMailer::Base

 def notify(payment_notification)
    @payment_notification = payment_notification
   mail to: **'xxxxxxxxx'**, subject: 'New order'
  end
end
```

Payment Notification from Paypal comes into the system with details of the transaction:
cart_id, line_item_id, product_title.

Line_item has a cart_id column, as well as a product_id column.

Product has a store_id column.

Store has a user_id column.

User has an **email address**.

Trying to find out how i can access this email address from my mailer and fire the email after the transaction.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using devise?

Comment: @Sravan Yes, i am. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring your associations, you can get the `user_email` as,

```
LineItem.find(@payment_notification.line_item_id).product.store.user.email
```

Mailer,

```
class PaymentNotifier < ActionMailer::Base

 def notify(payment_notification)
    @payment_notification = payment_notification
     mail to: LineItem.find(@payment_notification.line_item_id).product.store.user.email, subject: 'New order'
  end
end
```

Comment: if i used 'current_user.email' - wouldn't that just send to the logged in user?

Comment: but you said that the email should go to the store owner?

Comment: if you want to send the mail to the logged_in user, you can simply use, `current_user.email`, but of you want it to send it to store owner, check my answer.

Comment: Store owner, but a customer could be logged in buying a product from the store.

Comment: check now, sorry first updated `current_user` by mistake

Comment: `LineItem.find(@payment_notification.line_item_id).product.store.user.email`

Comment: This is what i got `undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126111/discussion-between-sravan-and-rails-learner).